# How to define a static member of a nested template (template class inside template class)

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class `S<T>` with a nested template class `S<T>::Q<M>`. The inner class contains a static instance of itself.

How do I encode the definition of `S<T>::Q<M>::q_` in the following code example? (The line marked with `<---- error`)

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {};
struct B {};

template<typename T>
struct S {

  template<typename M>
  struct Q {
    int x;
    Q() : x(1) {}

    static Q q_; 
  };
};

template<typename T, typename M>
typename S<T>::template Q<M> S<T>::Q<M>::q_; // <---- error

int main()
{
    std::cout << S<A>::Q<B>::q_.x;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define it in the following way:

```
template<typename T>
template<typename M>
S<T>::Q<M> S<T>::Q<M>::q_ = Q();
```